# How to close a btn using buttons and canvas?

Tags: jquery

I have some query to show and hide a box. the btn "normal-btn.interest" used is the trigger and you are able to click off the canvas $(document) to close the btn.

Can someone explain how I can add the button "normal-btn.interest" into the jquery to also close the box as well as having

```
$(document

    $('.normal-btn.interest').click(function(e){

            // Prevent the event from bubbling up the DOM tree
            e.stopPropagation();
            $('.categories-wrap').fadeIn();
        });

        $(document, '.normal-btn.interest').click(function(){
            $('.categories-wrap').fadeOut();
        });
```

Comment: Try using `show() & hide()`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9cQLD/

Answer (score 1):

`Escaping class name` will solve your problem if you applied class `normal-btn.interest` to your `element` then use it like `'.normal-btn\.interest` in place of `'.normal-btn.interest'` like,

```
$('.normal-btn\.interest').click(function(e){
   // Prevent the event from bubbling up the DOM tree
   e.stopPropagation();
   $('.categories-wrap').fadeIn(); // must be hidden, to fade in
});
$(document, '.normal-btn\.interest').click(function(){
    $('.categories-wrap').fadeOut(); // must be visible, to fade out
});
```

If the you have `applied two classes` then your code is **ok** no need to **escape**

Also after looking your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9cQLD/1) I saw there is no problem in your **code** you need to **change** only the **css** for **class categories-wrap**

Change the **position** from **fixed** to **absolute** and **decrease** the **top** like

```
position: absolute;
top: 40px;
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9cQLD/2/)**